# How to circumvent the lack of capability of extending enumerations?

Tags: java, enumeration

I am sorry ahead of time for how this question may turn out. I really can't think of a good way to word it.

I would very much like to have an enumeration extend another for the sake of use method abstraction. It would make life so much easier. Alas, I cannot. So, does anyone know how I may be able to implement a feature like an abstract method call? I tried an interface but quickly learned that you can't use an Enum generic.

Edit 1:
 I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539064/enum-abstraction-problem), I will look at it and see if I can derive my answer from the help. I will leave this open and unanswered just in case however.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enum abstraction problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539064/enum-abstraction-problem)

Comment: @EJP - As per my editted link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We often use the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) to allow extending enums with external functionality. Something like

```
boolean reallyLoveThisDay = dayOfWeek.accept(new DefaultDayOfWeekVisitor<Boolean>()
{
  public Boolean visitMonday(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) { return false; }
  public Boolean visitDefault(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) { return true; }
});
```

Comment: I'm also not entirely sure how this would work with enums. How do I maintain the enumerations... enumerability?

Comment: This may become large, but not complicated. Not sure what you mean by "enumerability". Generally, I see two possible reasons for extending an enum - adding an enum value or overriding/adding methods. Java enums are the wrong tool for the first reason anyway. For the second one, you can model an operation by a visitor. "Overriding" would mean using a different visitor. Extending visitors is trivial.