# AbstractClass InstanceOf specificClass not working

Tags: java, abstract-class

Hi have a strange error.

I have always used the `instanceof` for see the specific object of an abstract class,
But not run and I don't understand why.

I work for a `Java` project created with `spring boot` (`1.5.16.RELEASE`), is a maven project, with `JAVA8` and for my `MySql` db use `querydsl-jpa`.

I have an abstractClass for define the user for login.A single user can have only one role, and I have create an AbstractUser class:

```
    @Entity
@Audited
@Data
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="dType", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class AbstractUser extends AbstractDomainAudit{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7060362023055663647L;

    @Column(updatable=false, insertable=false)
    private String dType;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Transient
    private String newPassword;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Transient
    private String confirmNewPassword;

    @Column(nullable=false,unique=true, updatable=false)
    private String userName;

    private boolean able;

    private String name;

    @Email
    private String email;

}
```

One of my extender classes is the follow:

```
   @Entity
@Audited
@Data
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "Admin")
public class Administrators extends AbstractUser implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7061564146290031007L;
}
```

But when in my controller, I try to define the instanceof, not run:

```
@GetMapping(value="/{id}", params="form")
public String updateForm(@PathVariable(value="id") final Long id, final Model uiModel) {

    AbstractUser user = userService.findById(id);

    if(user instanceof Administrators) {
        Administrators u = (Administrators) user;
        uiModel.addAttribute(USER, u);

    }else if (user instanceof Commercial){
        Commercial ut = (Commercial) user;

        uiModel.addAttribute(USER, ut);
    }

    return UPDATE_PAGE;
}
```

My condition is ignored. 
And I don't understand why. Can anyone help me?

Comment: have you debugged which user did you get? can we see your userService.findById()?

Comment: Yes, in debugging the user type is correct,  but the condition is always ignored.

Comment: As far as I can see from your code, Administrators class extends AppUser class and not AbstractUser.

Comment: @ArtyomRebrov I edited the code. (In my project AbstractUser is AppUser, I have edit it in the question)

Comment: @Apo could you show your UserService, I suppose it should return an implementation class type either Commercial or Administrators.

Answer (score 0):

JPA-annotated Classes might be proxied at runtime. Try logging your instance's class

`user.getClass().getCanonicalName()`

Have a look here for example: [JPA, inheritance and instanceof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303662/jpa-inheritance-and-instanceof)